# jQuery How To Remove Class Once One Has Been Added

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to remove a class, let's call it "oldclass", once the new class has been added.

```
$( ".nav ul.menu li" ).mouseenter(function() { 
    $(this).addClass('animated fadeInDown')
}); // Once this new class is added, remove "oldclass"
```

What is the simplest way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`addClass` and `removeClass` operations are atomic, so just:

```
$(this).addClass('animated fadeInDown').removeClass('oldclass');
```

Another way is to use `toggleClass`:

```
$(this).toggleClass('animated fadeInDown oldclass');
```

... if `animated` and `fadeInDown` were not added previously.

Comment: Ok great, easy enough. Thanks.